# Why does every server I try say it can't connect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just re-purchased Minecraft (because my old profile stopped working so I bought it) after not playing it for a couple of months. I've added a bunch of servers, but almost every one says "can not connect."

I know its not because the server is not 1.7.2, because I checked that they'd update. It will say "server can't connect" after a long time. I don't know if its me or the servers.

My server screen looks like this (notice the one at the bottom – it's still loading!):

[image: Server Screen Screenshot]

Comment: Run-on sentences are bad because it makes it hard to understand them and it's less likely that someone will answer your question when that question is hard to understand and if you don't get an answer because people don't understand your question you'll be disappointed and you might not come back to the site if your first experience with it is disappointment so please use punctuation and don't write run-on sentences.

Comment: I can't help but notice at least one of those servers explicity says 1.6.4

Comment: @MBraedley run-on much?

Comment: @TheX take a look at the revision history.  I was using satire to make a point.

Comment: @MBraedley I know, I was just pointing out the irony...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, search 'Firewall' and go into 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security'. On the left click 'Outbound Rules' and right click to create a new rule. Make the rule for a port, which is '25565' and do this twice, once for UDP and once for TCP. This should allow outgoing connections to servers with the default Minecraft port that may not be currently connecting because of your firewall.

Comment: Pretty sure Windows Firewall would never block those connections by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was just experiencing this issue with my local server, these errors are popping up because the owners of the servers have not looked into the new eula and changed the text to "true". With 1.8 launching, Mojang has made a required eula that each server must agree to in order for the server to come online.

Comment: I just realized this question was from 10 months ago, but is being linked to for questions from today.. interestingly I think these are separate questions with the same issue. My answer should work for current issues with 1.8.