# Can't join any server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't join any minecraft servers because it keeps saying 'Can't connect to server' at every server i have. I can go on internet like post this question here.
What's happening?
[image]

Comment: Check your Firewall. If you are on something like "school network" - for example Eduroam, connections for this can be blocked. (In fact, on Eduroam it IS blocked)

Comment: @AntoineHejlík this question already is asked [**here**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139223/why-does-every-server-i-try-say-it-cant-connect)

Comment: @RudolfJelínek there it says that it still loads but for me it doesnt

Comment: Did you refresh the server list?

Comment: Are the server IPs correct? Did you verify that all of the server were working before? Try this server, and if it doesn't work let me know: ballooncraft.net no www. and no http://

Answer (score 0):

There are more things that can cause the problem:

- Firewall. Your WiFi Firewall can block some things, including Minecraft. Check your Wifi settings
- Minecraft. Try clicking the Reload button. Or maybe you have a too old version.
- Bad MC seission. Relaunch MC. **Do not close Minecraft with the cross, but with the `quit game` button.
- Something somewere went wrong. Load MC with your account form another device. If problems persist, reinstall MC (but make a backup) and try again.

If all of this doesn't work, contact Mojang, I don't know what is the problem.